# gcc doesn't select all files under -L/path/to/dir

Tags: gcc, linker

while running gmake (gcc) using -L/path/to/dir
the build is fails with- undefined symbol 'Curl_base64_decode'

after I change it to -L/path/to/dir/*
the build not breaks.

any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is about the linker, not make and not gcc.

Secondly, the `-L/path/to/dir` option tells the linker to look in `/path/to/dir` not in all its sub-directories.

So if using `-L /path/to/dir/*` works it means the library you want is actually in a sub-directory, and you should have a `-L` option for that sub-directory

Comment: Thanks for the answer it make sense, under /path/to/dir I have 2 symbolic link and one shared object, no subdirs

Comment: Then you need to provide more information about the precise commands and contents of the directory

Comment: maybe it doesnt do anything on this dir and that is whay I'm not getting this error when I run -L/path/to/dir/* ? -L/path/to/dir/* goes to nowhere?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not psychic, you haven't provided enough information to get a proper answer.